# $http.post returns status code 0 even if post is created in database

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular, and in my controller I want to save my order. I use $http and the code looks like this:

```
$http({method: "post", url:$scope.saveOrderUrl}
    ).success(function (data) {
        $scope.order = data;
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        alert("Error when saving order. Status: " + status);
    });
```

The order is created in the database, but http.post is returning an error with status code 0. The error alert appears before the api controller has been able to return a success response back to the view.

Am I doing something wrong? What is it that determines if http returns a success or an erro when it doesn't wait for the server?

Comment: Which HTTP code did the server return after a successful insert?

Answer (score 3):

try again with code below:

```
$http.post(url).success(function(data){
    $scope.order = data;
}).error(function(msg){
    alert(msg);
});
```